# C swapping strings in 2d array (without pointers)

Tags: c, arrays

I wrote a function that sorts an array of strings by their length

```
void lenSort(char sen[][NAME_LENGTH], int len)
{
    int i = 0, j = 0, k = 0;
    char tmp[NAME_LENGTH] = {0};
    for(i = 0; i < len - 1; i++)
    {
        for(j = 0; j < len - i - 1; j++)
        {
            if(strlen(sen[j]) > strlen(sen[j+1]))
            {
                strncpy(tmp, sen[j], strlen(sen[j]));
                for(k = 0; k < strlen(sen[j]); k++)
                {
                    sen[j][k] = 0;
                }
                strncpy(sen[j], sen[j+1], strlen(sen[j+1]));
                strncpy(sen[j+1], tmp, strlen(tmp));
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The array I pass is: `{"12345", "123", "123456", "12", "1234", "1234", "1234567", "123", "1", "12345"}`
For some reason when I copy `sen[j+1]` into `sen[j]` I get excess characters, I thought that that's becuase `sen[j]` is longer, but I reset it before copying and it still happens and I don't have any clue why..

Comment: `for(k = 0; k < strlen(tmp); k++)
                {
                    tmp[k] = 0;
                }` - What do you think this does?

Comment: I copy `sen[j]` into `tmp`, if `tmp` is longer than it would have excess characters also

Comment: You can just delete that code - it is not required  - you are doing a copy afterwards so its contents does not matter.

Comment: Ditto with the other for loop

Comment: The problem is that in the 1st iteration for example, `sen[j+1]` (123) is copied into `sen[j]` (12345), but its value stays 12345

Comment: @Daniel. Just use strcpy instead of the strncpy. Also this loop for(k = 0; k < strlen(sen[j]); k++)
                {
                    sen[j][k] = 0;
                }
 does not make sense.

Comment: We are only allowed to use `strncpy`, and yes without the loop its the same thing.. I'm so confused

Comment: don't call `strlen` again and again, especially inside a loop. Store the length in a variable and reuse it

Comment: The length changes (suppose to atleast) so I call it again

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to sort strings based on their length only then inner below for loop is not required though it may serving some other purpose

```
for(k = 0; k < strlen(sen[j]); k++)
                {
                    sen[j][k] = 0;
                }
```

here is the my solution. use `strcpy()` instead of `strncpy()` because strings copied using `strncpy()` are not null terminated. from the **man** page of `strncpy`
*Warning: If there is no null byte among the first n  bytes
       of src, the string placed in dest will not be null-terminated.*

```
void lenSort(char sen[][NAME_LENGTH], int len)
{
    int i = 0, j = 0, k = 0;
    char tmp[NAME_LENGTH] = {0};
    for(i = 0; i < len - 1; i++)
    {
        for(j = 0; j < len - i - 1; j++)
        {
            if(strlen(sen[j]) > strlen(sen[j+1]))
            {
                strcpy(tmp, sen[j]);
                strcpy(sen[j], sen[j+1]);
                strcpy(sen[j+1], tmp);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Is there a way to mimic this using `strncpy`? or do I have to use `strcpy`?